# Symfony 2 Assetic. Don't see single css or js file

Tags: php, symfony, assetic

When I add such lines in my layout.html.php:

```
<?php foreach ($view['assetic']->stylesheets(
    array('@AnglerBackendBundle/Resources/public/css/*')
    ) as $url
    ): ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= $view->escape($url) ?>" />
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Config:

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    # java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        # closure:
        #     jar: %kernel.root_dir%/java/compiler.jar
        yui_css:
             jar: %kernel.root_dir%/java/yuicompressor.jar
        yui_js:
             jar: %kernel.root_dir%/java/yuicompressor.jar
```

I see 5 tags link with 5 resourses but according to Symfony 2 docs I should see only one file.
What I did wrong

Comment: Are you testing it in the development environment? If so, this is normal behaviour. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html : "In the dev environment, each file is still served individually, so that you can debug problems more easily. However, in the prod environment, this will be rendered as a single script tag."

Comment: It is so in both of environments.

Comment: Moreover I can see single file in css folder but still can't understand why it isn't used

Comment: Guys all is correct. Previously I set debug parameter of AppKernel as true in app.php. Now it works

Answer (score 4):

Just to put the answer in an actual answer:

You need to change this:
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);

To this:
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);

The second parameter is the debug parameter.  Assetic will only write one file if debugging is off.